# 規模の大きいサイトでは、あらかじめ作ってある企業のHTMLテンプレートがあるのでしょうか

Tags: html

お答えしてくれると嬉しいです。
Amazon,Amebaなど規模の大きいサイトでは、htmlをスクラッチするのではなく、あらかじめ作ってある企業のhtmlテンプレートにテキストやリンク、画像を埋め込んでいるのでしょうか？　そうでないと大変だと思うのですが...実際のところどう書いているのでしょうか？

Comment: 例えばAmazonだと商品をカートに入れて、注文して・・・といったユーザーの操作に応じてページの内容が変化したり、メールを送信したりといった、あらかじめテンプレートに埋め込んだHTMLを作っておくだけでは解決できない動きもありますが、これはどこかでプログラムが動いているのだろう、というところまでは想像できますか？

Comment: @unarist♦ 回答ありがとうございます。プログラムが動作していることは把握していますが、どんなコードか全く想像がつきません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そういったサイトではサーバー上のプログラムでHTMLを生成していることが多いです。全体としては

- ブラウザからの入力を受け取り
- それをもとに必要なデータを集めたり、その他の処理を行い
- ブラウザにHTMLを出力する

という流れになりますが、このHTML生成にあたってはサイト内で共通のテンプレートやページごとのテンプレートなどを用意しておき、それらを組み合わせ、またプログラムで取得生成したデータを埋め込む、といったパターンが多いかと思います。

こういったHTMLの埋め込み処理を行うプログラムはテンプレートエンジンと呼ばれるので、このキーワードで検索すると色んな例が見られるかと思います。

なおブログなどでは最終的なHTMLが変化しないことが多いですから、生成したHTMLを保存しておき、再びアクセスがあった際はそれを表示するだけ、という場合もあります。さらにはJekyllのように生成したHTMLだけをサーバーにアップロードすることもありますね。

Answer (score 2):

> 実際のところどう書いているのでしょうか？

実際のところは分かりませんが、一般的なWebアプリケーションであれば次のような技術を使って書いてると思います。

- CGI
- Java EE (Servlet)
- PHP
- Active Server Page
- Etc..

また、Springとかrailsとかそのへんのフレームワークを用いることで上記の技術をプログラマから見えなくするのが現在は主流？のように感じます。